# Scraper Python and YouTube API

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, youtube

would like to **scrape** youtube for some channels stats and lo learn how it works. And than to make csv for the following analysis. Used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qtC-tsQ-wE) to create and to learn.

I have 2 files:
main.py, youtube_statistics

**main.py**

```
from youtube_statistics import YTstats

API_KEY = "xxx"
channel_id = "xxx"

yt = YTstats(API_KEY, channel_id)
yt.get_channel_statistics()
```

**youtube_statistics.py**

```
class YTstats:
    def_init_(self, api_key, channel_id)
    self.api_key = api_key
    self.channel_id = channel_id
    self.channel_statistics = None


def get_channel_statistics(self):
    url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={self.channel_id}&key={self.api_key}'
    print(url)
```

This is not all code, but tries to run main called errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/!Python/YouTube API/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from youtube_statistics import YTstats
  File "D:\!Python\YouTube API\youtube_statistics.py", line 1, in <module>
    class YTstats:
  File "D:\!Python\YouTube API\youtube_statistics.py", line 2, in YTstats
    def_init_(self, api_key, channel_id)
NameError: name 'def_init_' is not defined
```

What going wrong, how to fix? On video everything is works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python indentation matters. Your *youtube_statistics.py* file was indented wrong. Particularly the class initialization was declared wrong. Here is the fixed version:

```
class YTstats:
    def __init__(self, api_key, channel_id):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.channel_id = channel_id
        self.channel_statistics = None


    def get_channel_statistics(self):
        url = f'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={self.channel_id}&key={self.api_key}'
        print(url)
```

Comment: Thanks @mechanical_meat, I spotted the typo after answering but you beat me to it! :)

Comment: No problem brother!